# Unclear Segmentation fault of using Boost Coroutine(1.55)?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, move, boost-coroutine

I write a piece of code which will get a `Segmentation fault`. I am not sure whether it is a bug of Boost Coroutine or my code below:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/coroutine/coroutine.hpp>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
using C = boost::coroutines::coroutine<T()>;

string foo(C<string>::caller_type & yield,
           std::string fn, int cnt) {
  std::ifstream f(fn);
  // f.close();
  int local_cnt = 0;
  while(local_cnt < cnt) {
      string l;
      getline(f, l);
      local_cnt ++;
      yield(l);
  }
  f.close();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  vector<C<string> > result;
  for(int i = 0; i < 8192; ++i) {
    C<string> obj(bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1, "test.txt", 3)); // line I
    result.push_back(std::move(obj)); // line J
  }
  return 0;
}
```

`test.txt` is very large so it will never get the eof before segfault occurring. I use 1.55 of Boost and there are some observation:

1. seg-error occured in `line I`
2. If I delete or move `f.close()` before yield clause, seg-error disappeared.
3. If I delete `line J` in the code, seg-error disappeared.
4. If I use a smaller number in stead of `8192`(say 512), seg-error disappeared.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Have you checked where the segfault is occuring? Looking at your code, you are most likely segfaulting because f is invalid when try to close it. Most likely because it went out of scope when control passed between the co-routine instance and the next iteration of the loop. this should be easy to see in a debugger though.

Comment: @tmruss see my update~ "f is invalid when try to close it" why and where should I do this close op? The segfault occurred in `line I`

Comment: @xunzhang Can you post the stack trace as well in that case? Should be easy to grab from the debugger.

Comment: @tmruss the `strace` info say that `Too many open files`, I am not sure move will run the foo function before actually get lines from coroutines variable `result`?

Comment: @xunzhang not strace, the stack trace at time of crash. You should be able to get that from the core dump and/or debugger.

Comment: @xunzhang The reason you are getting too many open file is because you are opening and reading the file on every coroutine instance, which you are creating 8192 of (because you are moving the object into the vector. Is there a reason why you don't read the file upfront then parse the result as a string?

Comment: What if you split line I into two lines, one with the bind, the other constructing the coroutine? Further, you say that not calling `f.close()` (which is otherwise useless since the scope does that itself) causes the bug to go away. What happens with that if you actually collect the input from the coroutines? Just stepping off `main()` will probably terminate those implicitly then. That said, it is highly ineffective to read hundreds of files in parallel because you typically don't have hundreds of harddrives which could satisfy those parallel read requests.

Answer (score 1):

"Too many open files" - you exceed the max number of open file descriptors

> If I use a smaller number in stead of 8192(say 512), seg-error disappeared.

the seg fault will happen inside the ifstream (does not throw)
check ulimit -n
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
sysctl